# SpriteKit - Stop an object bouncing

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

How I stop and object that falls from the top of the screen to the bottom of the screen from bouncing. Here is the code for that object:

```
- (SKNode*)addRock {
    SKSpriteNode* rock = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"asteroid"];
    rock.position=CGPointMake ([self makeRandomXWBetween:0 and:self.size.width],self.size.height);
    rock.name = @"rock";
    rock.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:rock.size];
    rock.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
    rock.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
    [self addChild:rock];

    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set the restitution property of SKPhysicsBody.

```
rock.physicsBody.restitution = 0.0;
```

According to Apple's [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/restitution):

> This property is used to determine how much energy the physics body
>   loses when it bounces off another object. The property must be a value
>   between 0.0 and 1.0. The default value is 0.2.

Comment: the restitution property is the correct answer here. Just to elaborate slightly if wanted the object to bounce on some contact and not others, once you set up your contact delegation method you could set the velocity to 0, 0 on the detection of said contacts.

Comment: I would like to add that sometimes you'd want the **friction** property set to **0.0** as well. Otherwise, on collision a physics body might still cause a sprite to move slightly, even if the restitution is 0.